# Unsuccessful startup of Gateway LT27

Tags: boot, gateway

I turn on my Gateway LT27 and get the message "No bootable device - Please restart system".  If I hit F2 to get into setup mode, it just hangs.  Once in a while, when I reboot, I randomly press a bunch of keys on the left side of the keyboard and it miraculously takes me into windows and works fine so the disk is ok.  When I first had the problem, I could still get into F2, but after trying different options there, I'm pretty sure I messed things up and removed everything from the startup list.  What to do?

Comment: If F2 takes you into the BIOS, there should be an option to reset all changes and revert to defaults. Just select that, ensure the laptop's hard disk is set as the first boot device, save all changes and reboot.